# Find the values $a>0$ for which this improper integral converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Find the values of $a > 0$ for which the improper integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x} {x^a} dx$$ converges.

This question is from my analysis quiz (now over).

I have studied improper integrals but Dirichlet test, Comparison tests and other results can't be used in this case as Dirichlet test is used if $\sin x$ used to tend to $\infty$, also 2 comparison tests are not suited for two functions inside the integral.

If I use Abel test and write
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x} {x^a} dx = \int_{0}^{a} \frac{\sin x} {x^a} dx + \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x} {x^a} dx$$
then $\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x} {x^a} dx$ converges at infinity for $a<1$ but  $\sin x$ is not bounded and monotonic in $(a, \infty)$. So, it can't be used as well.

So, what result should I use. (I have done a course on real analysis.)

Comment: $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^a}\,dx$ converges (absolutely) for $a>1$

Comment: If  $a > 0$ the area under the graph of $\frac{\sin x}{x^a}$ consists of arches that are alternately above and below the axis, with areas decreasing to $0$.  This should remind you of the alternating series test.

Comment: why cant u just use integration by parts?

Comment: @mathworker21 A good question!

Comment: @UmbertoP. It's true that if we have a sequence $0 = a_0 < a_1 < \ldots$ s.t. $f$ doesn't change sign on $(a_k, a_{k + 1})$, $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k = \infty$ and $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \int_{a_k}^{a_{k + 1}} f(x) \, dx$ converges, then the improper integral $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$ converges, but it's not completely trivial to prove that (to show that the limit of $\int_0^{x_n}$ exists for any sequence $(x_n)$, one can take the nearest $a_k$ to the left/right of $x_n$ depending on the sign of $f(x_n)$ and apply the squeeze theorem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let us split the integral into two parts:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x} {x^a} \, dx
= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin x} {x^a} \, dx
+ \int_{\pi}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x} {x^a} \, dx
.
$$

The first integral,
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin x} {x^a} \, dx
= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x+O(x^3)} {x^a} \, dx
= \int_{0}^{\pi} (x^{1-a}+O(x^{3-a})) \, dx
$$
is convergent if $1-a>-1,$ i.e. if $a<2.$

The second integral,
$$
\int_{\pi}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x} {x^a} \, dx
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{\sin x} {x^a} \, dx
$$
is an alternating series where the terms decrease in absolute value to zero monotonically for every $a>0$ so it is convergent for all $a>0$ by the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Thus, the original integral converges if $a<2.$

Comment: "alternating series where the terms decrease to zero monotonically" should be "alternating series where the terms **in absolute value** decrease to zero monotonically "

Comment: @zhw. True. I was a bit sloppy there. I have now added that.

Comment: @md2perpe How does you deduced that $
= \int_{0}^{\pi} (x^{1-a}+O(x^{3-a})) \, dx$?  is convergent if a<2. It  is clear that $x^{1-a}$  is convergent if 2>a and $O(x^{3-a})$ a<3. But how to  deduce that  for $x^{1-a} + O(x^{1-a}$?

Comment: @md2perpe You didn't proved in part (2) that in k$\pi$ to (k+1) $\pi$ $|a_n|$ decreases monotonically.

Comment: @No-One. I left it to you to work out the details. Isn't it obvious that $\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x^a} \, dx$ is both alternating and decreases in absolute value when $a>0$? For the other integral you can instead use $$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x^a}\,dx < \int_0^\pi \frac{x}{x^a}\,dx = \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{x^{a-1}}\,dx < \infty.$$

Comment: @md2perpe   I understood that $ \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1} {x^{a-1}} dx$  is convergent for a<2 but unable to deduce that  $\int_{( k+1) \pi}^{k \pi} \frac{sin x} {x^a} dx $ is decreasing in absolute value as sin x is not absolutely decreasing or increasing in $k\pi$ to $(k+1) \pi$. I certainly needs a rigorous argument. Your way of proving is good and I can  award you bounty if you are willing to answer my comment  before time.

Comment: $$
\left|\int_{( k+1) \pi}^{k \pi} \frac{\sin x} {x^a} \, dx\right|
\leq \int_{( k+1) \pi}^{k \pi} \left|\frac{\sin x} {x^a}\right| \,dx
\leq \int_{( k+1) \pi}^{k \pi} \frac{1} {x^a} \, dx
\\
\leq \int_{( k+1) \pi}^{k \pi} \frac{1} {(k\pi)^a} \, dx
= \frac{\pi} {(k\pi)^a}
= \frac{\pi^{1-a}}{k^a}
\searrow 0
$$
when $a>0.$

Comment: @No-One. And it's alternating since $\operatorname{sign}(\sin x) = (-1)^{k}$ on the interval $(k\pi, (k+1)\pi).$

Comment: It seems some malicious people have been downvoting all of the answers without explanation; even yours, the rewarded answer, had -2 votes.

Comment: @ArjunVyavaharkar. There is actually one answer without downvotes: the one by Matthew Pilling.

Answer (score 3):

**Fact #1**: The improper integral $\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^a}\mathrm{d}x$ converges for all $a>0$

**Proof of Fact #1**: Let $t>\pi$. From integration by parts, $$\int_\pi^t\frac{\sin x}{x^a}\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\cos t}{t^a}-\frac{1}{\pi^a}-a \int_{\pi}^{t}\frac{\cos x}{x^{a+1}}\mathrm{d}x$$ Since $a>0$ we know $\frac{\cos t}{t^a}\rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ by squeeze theorem. Moreover $a+1>1$ and $\bigg|\frac{\cos x}{x^{a+1}}\bigg|\leq \frac{1}{x^{a+1}}$ for any $x>0$ so $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\int_{\pi}^{t}\frac{\cos x}{x^{a+1}}\mathrm{d}x$ exists. In fact, $\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^{a+1}}\mathrm{d}x$ converges *absolutely*. This show our integral converges for $a>0$.

**Fact #2**: The improper integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x^a}\mathrm{d}x$ converges if and only if $a<2$.

**Proof of Fact #2**: Since $\frac{\sin x}{x}\rightarrow 1$ as $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ there is $0<\delta < \pi$ so that $\Bigg|\frac{\sin x}{x}-1\Bigg|<\frac{1}{2}$ for $0<x<\delta$. This means $\frac{1}{2x^{a-1}}<\frac{\sin x}{x^a}<\frac{3}{2x^{a-1}}$ for $x\in (0,\delta)$. Because $\int_{0}^{\delta}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{a-1}}$ converges if and only if $a<2$ we get with direct comparison test $\int_0^{\delta}\frac{\sin x}{x^a}\mathrm{d}x$ converges if and only if $a<2$. The result follows by noting $\int_\delta^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x^a}\mathrm{d}x$ isn't even improper.

Combine Fact #1 and Fact #2 to see how $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^a}\mathrm{d}x$ converges if and only if $a<2$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit that I'm not very good at proofs, but I believe I've got something; I have reason to believe the following:

$$ \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x^{1+\frac{1}{\alpha}}} \textrm{d}x = \alpha \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2\alpha}\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}\right) $$

I believe this holds for all $\alpha\in(1,\infty)$, or rather $a\in[1,2)$ if you wanna revert to the original integral. I'll leave some updates later on if additional information is required.

**Disclaimer:**
Just for clarification, I am establishing that this *identity* holds for all $a\in[1,2)$, not necessarily that the integral in question converges for only $a\in[1,2)$. So far, this is only the beginning, and I plan to add later details in the future in case I stumble across any more values of $a$ for which the integral converges.

---

**Edit 1:** I forgot to specify that the following integral DEFINITELY converges for all $a\in(0,2)$:

$$ \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x^a} \textrm{d}x = \dfrac{\cos\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)\Gamma(2-a)}{1-a} $$

The reason why the interval only runs from $0$ to $2$ is because, when $a=2$, the RHS is equal to $\dfrac{\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{2}\right)\Gamma(2-2)}{1-2}$ or $\Gamma(0)$, which we know blows up to infinity. Conversely, when $a=0$, the RHS is equal to $1$, which can't happen because $\int_0^\infty \sin(x) \textrm{d}x$ doesn't converge.